# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence while training KD TRee on TFIDF

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, knn, tf-idf

I am trying to train a KD-Tree on TF-IDF of a document corpus but it gives

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The code and the error description are below. Can someone help me figure out the problem?

Code:

```
t0 = time.time()
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print "TF-IDF built:", total

#######################------------------------############################

t0 = time.time()
#nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=20, algorithm='kd_tree', metric='euclidean')
#nbrs.fit(X_train_tfidf)#,Y)
nbrs = KDTree(np.array(X_train_tfidf), leaf_size=100) 


t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print "KNN Trained:", total

#######################------------------------############################
```

This is the error:

```
TF-IDF built: 0.108999967575
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tfidf_knn.py", line 48, in <module>
    nbrs = KDTree(np.array(X_train_tfidf), leaf_size=100)
  File "sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi", line 1055, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.__init__ (sklearn\neighbo
rs\kd_tree.c:8298)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 474, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X_train_tfidf is a sparse matrix ([scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)) and in order to be converted to a numpy array, you need to do . [toarray()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix.toarray) . This examples run for me:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import time
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix # sparse format compatible with sklearn models
from  sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors


import numpy as np
X=[ 'I Love dogs' ,
'you love cats',
' He loves Birds',
' she loves lizards',
' None loves me'
]
t0 = time.time()
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print "TF-IDF built:", total

#######################------------------------############################

t0 = time.time()
nbrs = KDTree(X_train_tfidf.toarray(), leaf_size=100) 

################## for sparse input we cannot use kdtree, but we can use brute #################
#nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=20, algorithm='kd_tree')
#nbrs.fit(csr_matrix(X_train_tfidf))#,Y)


t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print "KNN Trained:", total
```

Printed :

```
TF-IDF built: 0.00499987602234
KNN Trained: 0.029000043869
```

Comment: Thanks  for the help! However, it worked on small data but when it give it a huge array --- I get back a memory because after I do "toarray()" -- the matrix is not sparse anymore.
Is there a way to give a sparse matrix to KDTree?

Comment: Hey . see my edit. You cannot use kd_tree with sparse input, but you can change the method to brute. Results should not be that much different. You also need to convert your sparse matrix to another form (csr_matrix) which is more compatible with sklearn models.